# Saving loop output in R using the rootSolve package

Tags: r

I'm a game theorist, trying to simulate the solutions of an arms race model using a nested loop in R.
Specifically, I'm trying find the roots of (1-delta)*(0.1+(1.1-0.1)*x)/(1-delta*x)-x=0 using the uni.root function in the rootSolve package. uni.root identifies all roots of the equation. In this case there is either 0,1 or 2 roots.

```
for(mu in seq(0,1,0.2)){
for(delta in seq(0,1,0.2)){
G <- function (x) (1-delta)*(mu+(1.1-mu)*x)/(1-delta*x)-x 
roots <- uniroot.all(G, c(0, 1))
parameter <- c(mu,delta)
print(parameter)
print(roots)}}
```

I would like to retrieve an output matrix or dataframe that lists the parameter values (mu and delta) and the solutions (if any) in rows. Something like the following:

```
m1<-expand.grid(seq(0,1,0.2),seq(0,1,0.2))
m<-cbind(m1,c(NA,NA,runif(34)),c(NA,runif(35)))
dimnames(m) = list(1:36,c("mu","delta","root1","root2"))
```

where NA appears whenever a solution is lacking.

Using the apply function has been unsuccessful as the outcome I receive is in lists.

Please, help. Your answer can help make the world a better place.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you adopt this program:

```
 roots <- matrix(list(),6,6);  
for(mu in seq(0,1,0.2)){

   for(delta in seq(0,1,0.2)){
      G <- function (x) (1-delta)*(mu+(1.1-mu)*x)/(1-delta*x)-x 
      roots[1+mu*5, 1+delta*5] <- 
        if( inherits( rt<- try(uniroot(G, c(0, 1))), "try-error")){NA 
                                                                  }else{ list(rt) }
      parameter <- c(mu,delta)
      print(parameter)
}}
```

You get mostly errors from uniroot but there are 5 successful runs:

```
> roots
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 NA  
[2,] NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA  
[3,] NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA  
[4,] NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA  
[5,] NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA  
[6,] NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

If you then use rootSolve::uniroot.all you get:

```
roots <- matrix(list(),6,6);  for(mu in seq(0,1,0.2)){
for(delta in seq(0,1,0.2)){
G <- function (x) (1-delta)*(mu+(1.1-mu)*x)/(1-delta*x)-x 
roots[1+mu*5, 1+delta*5] <- if( inherits( rt<- try(uniroot.all(G, c(0, 1))), "try-error")){NA}else{list(rt)}
parameter <- c(mu,delta)
print(parameter)
}}

> roots
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0         Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 0   
[2,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 0   
[3,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 0   
[4,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 0   
[5,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 0   
[6,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,2 0
```

Which is somewhat different because `uniroot.all` returns a zero-length result when the input is erroneous.

```
> roots[5,5]
[[1]]
[1] 0.2065142 0.9684933

> roots[6,1]
[[1]]
numeric(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your suggestion helped my find the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found

```
p=5 #refinement of interval partition for delta
q=5 #refinement of interval partition for mu
fix <- matrix(list(),(p+1)*(q+1),4)
P <- function(x) {if(length(x)==0) c(NA,NA) 
        else if(length(x)==1) c(0,0) 
        else x} # P converts 'no root result' (numeric(0)) into a vector c(NA,NA)
for(mu in seq(0,1,1/q)){
for(delta in seq(0,1,1/p)){
G <- function (x) (1-delta)*(mu+(1.1-mu)*x)/(1-delta*x)-x 
r <- uniroot.all(G, c(0, 1))
fix[p*delta+(p+1)*q*mu+1,] <- c(mu,delta,P(r))
print(c(mu,delta))
print(r)
}}

dimnames(fix) = list(1:((p+1)*(q+1)),c("mu","delta","root1","root2"))
fix
```